# asus phone data recovery with broken screen

Tags: data-recovery

I have Asus Zenfone selfie but the screen is broken and black and unfortunately USB debugging is not yet enabled.is there any way to recover data from it .please help. thank you

Comment: Is the phone protected by a pattern, pin or password?

Comment: I would replace the display. But I agree, you have a problem.

Comment: flash (adb enabled) magisk_patched.img from QPST and control your screen with scrcpy. for better answer better question is expected first (modelno ZD551KL? android 6? bootloader state?)